# javascript better import hook without navigating through relative folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

something which is bothering me when writing tests in my folder structure is the following thing:

```
//App
meteor/imports/api/tasks.js

//test
meteor/test/imports/api/tasks.test.js
```

So now when i import something from tasks.js i go like `import { task } from '../../../imports/api/tasks.js'` and my folder structure gets much bigger than this.

is there a better solution?

I was thinking of an import hook, maybe in the root tests directory, so i can import all the things from there, and when i am on the test, i can import from the import hook and don't have to do all the `../../../../` navigation.

Comment: Use the root, i.e. count the path from the root, and place `/` in front of the path.

Comment: root = root of my meteor project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using babel, you can add [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) to your babel configuration.

> A Babel plugin to add a new resolver for your modules when compiling
>   your code using Babel. This plugin allows you to add new "root"
>   directories that contain your modules. It also allows you to setup a
>   custom alias for directories, specific files, or even other npm
>   modules.

The module resolver may collide with webpack2 module handling, so you'll want to limit it just to tests:

**.babelrc example:**

```
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        ["module-resolver", {
          "root": ["./meteor/imports"]
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: is this working with mocha? I tried `"root": ["./"]` and `"root": ["./src"]`  but still have problems resolving the modules.

Comment: I'm using it with babel and jest. Just to check, try moving the plugins to the root of the .babelrc (without the env/test).

Comment: If it works, the problem is with the env definition, and I'll show you how to fix that.

Comment: I use babel, my test command is: `node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am on both Windows and Linux, atm i am working (testing) on Windows first. IDK if this is relevant for my Question, but on Windows i have no meteor installation, just node / npm.

Comment: Install cross-env from npm. Then change the test command in package.json to "cross-env NODE_ENV=test node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register". Although I think that "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register" should work as well.

Comment: Tried it on windows and edited my package.json: `"mocha-test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --require babel-register --recursive tests/mocha",`will result in `'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: You've forgottern the `cross-env` at the start -> ` cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register`.

Comment: And don't forget to install cross-env from npm

Comment: I'm glad to hear. Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
/imports/api/tasks.js
```

instead of

```
../../../imports/api/tasks.js
```

The / to start with marks root.

Comment: does it work from mocha test run? (I tried but it didn't work)

Comment: @Gobliins can you explain how did you try it and how it did not work for you?

Comment: I try to do to this import from my test cases, i run my tests with `node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register` and when i changed the relative path to `/imports/api/tasks` i get the `cannot find module`error

Comment: @Gobliins did you miss the .js at the end of the path?

Comment: checked, it's there